# Чи усталене в українській мові слово "шарм"? Перекладаю слово charm

Tags: переклад, from-english, вживання-слів, фразеологізми

Перекладав слово charm українською, поліз до [e2u.org.ua](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=charm&dicts=all&highlight=on), там для іменника тільки один переклад, `чар` (чари), пошукав саме `шарм` у тому ж словнику - мене перенаправляють на `чар`.

Добре, пішов до [yenotes](https://www.yenotes.com/en/?q=charm&from_lang=en&to_lang=uk), тут знайшов `чарівливість`, `чарівність`, але `шарму` знову немає.

Пішов дивитися в [SUM](http://sum.in.ua), там такого слова немає.

З іншого боку, таке слово є у цьому [словнику](http://slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D8%C0%D0%CC), а також у цьому [словнику іншомовних слів](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Qry=%D8%E0%F0%EC).

Не можу зрозуміти, де б так перевірити, щоби точно знати, чи можна у перекладі художньої книги використати це слово, бо воно пасує якнайкраще саме у цьому вигляді.

Comment: Альтернативно: [*чарівливість*](http://sum.in.ua/s/charivlyvistj), [*чарівність*](http://sum.in.ua/s/charivnistj), [*принада*](http://sum.in.ua/s/prynada). Хоча, в [орфографічному словнику від Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) є й *шарм*

Comment: Можна просто [чари](http://sum.in.ua/s/chary) й брати звідси похідні слова, покриває майже всі контексти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово очевидно є, хоча те, наскільки воно оптимальне, питання окреме.

[Є](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC) в [орфографічному словнику від Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) <sub>(дякую за [коментар](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1519/#comment4024_1519), Oksana Gubrenko)</sub>.

Є безліч траплянь в [корпусі](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx):

- > І дійсно, що за жінка — не красуня, але тон, шарм, — блискуча! <sub>Улас Самчук «Чого не гоїть огонь» (1959).</sub>
- > Юному товариству зрозуміло, що перед ними дипломатська пара, мабуть, з сов'єтамбасади, нічого ведмежого в них, в манерах є навіть привабливість, своєрідний шарм. <sub>Олесь Гончар «Твоя зоря» (1980).</sub>
- > Вдова виводить її на прогулянку, завжди з нею розмовляє, — така субтельна старенька, з дивним головним убором зі старовинною шпилькою, не позбавлена свого шарму, — кажуть, у неї був закоханий Фейербах, що їй додає загадковості в очах сусідів. <sub>Ліна Костенко «Записки українського самашедшого» (2010).</sub>